# MySQL error handling for returning the first error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, rollback

I checked the post here and the MySQL manual and I get part of the answer.

Question:
I have some query that can cause errors,, I want to handle them and have a message for the first error happened + line number + rollback (if there is an error).

The part of answer that I have:

- Return the code and error message.
- Rollback all of the queries if there is an error.

The part of answer that I don't have

- The first error (the code return the last error).
- Line number.

I know there is some errors in the code because I got each part from one site and mixed them LOL

The codes:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prod()
BEGIN
    DECLARE is_rolback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE resultError TEXT;
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMsg TEXT;
    DECLARE ErrorRows INT;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SET is_rolback = 1;
    END;


    START TRANSACTION;
    SET autocommit = 0;


-- The codes for checking the errors possible
-- Start
    insert into table1 values (2, 'B'); -- Correct
    insert into table1 values (1, 'A'); -- Error id 1 is already in database;
    insert into table1 values ('C');    -- Error should pass also the ID
-- End  

    IF is_rolback THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS ErrorRows = ROW_COUNT;
        SET resultError = CONCAT('Failed, error = ',errorCode,', line = ', ErrorRows, ', message = ',errorMsg);
        select resultError;

        select * from table1;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL prod();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prod;
```

The output:

```
Failed, error = 21S01, line = 0, message = Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
id      name
1       A
```

Comment: your output error message saying that you haven't mapped all the column in your insert query . Change your insert query with specifying column name and you will get rid of it

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Yes I know, it's just an easy example to show the problem. There is 2 errors in my codes that I put deliberately to show you that I get just the last error and I don't have line number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (it's more pseudo code than PLSQL but just to show you the idea).

- put your insert statements in an array of varchars or mediumtexts (maybe read from a sql file?)
- keep the HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION as it is and start the transaction
- for each statement in the array and while isRolback = 0:

```
    SET @q = currentStatement;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    IF NOT isRollback THEN
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
```

- outside of the loop keep the if block you have already

```
    IF is_rolback THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        ...
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
```